# Who is in the Amazing Spider-Man Post Credits Scene?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man

In the post credits scene in [The Amazing Spider-Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/) (2012),

> Dr. Curt Connors (The Lizard) is in a jail cell. He has a conversation with someone. Who is this person or villain?

The script is something like:

> *(Dr. Conner is lead to his cell. There is lightning outside in the storm.)* 
>  **Unknown man**: Hello Doctor. Did you tell the boy? 
>  Dr. Conner: Tell him what? 
>  **Unknown man**: Did you tell the boy the truth about his father? 
>  Dr. Conner: No. 
>  **Unknown man**: Well, that's very good. We'll let him be for now. 
>  Dr. Conner: You should leave him alone! 
>  *(Lightning strikes again in the storm. End scene.)*

Who was this mysterious person?

Comment: According to Rhys Ilfans the actor who played Dr Curt Connors/The Lizard, [it is NOT Norman Osborne](http://www.aintitcool.com/node/56771), but someone who is employed by him.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Director Marc Webb has said that originally, the Unknown Man in the post-credits scene of *The Amazing Spider-Man* [was conceived as being Electro](http://www.slashfilm.com/sinister-six-mysterio-confirmed/). Plans obviously changed though, as Electro was not created in-universe until the events of *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*.

Instead, the end ([and credits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1872181/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)) of *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* reveals the "[man in the hat](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0434064/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t16)"

[image: The man in the hat]

or "[man in the shadows](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)"

[image: The man in the shadows]

to be...

[Gustav Fiers, aka "The Gentleman"](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/gentlemn.htm).

[image: the gentleman]

In a set of Spider-Man books, Fiers assembles a version of [The Sinister Six](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinister_Six) in an effort to attack Peter Parker in an attempt to exact revenge for the actions of Peter's parents.

In *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*,

> we see Fiers conspiring with Harry Osborne to put together a team using equipment from Oscorp Labs.

Comment: Originally, the man in the ASM1 credits was going to be Electro: http://www.slashfilm.com/sinister-six-mysterio-confirmed/

Answer (score 16):

Comic book-based spoilers:

> Gwen Stacy is most famous for her death, so it is likely that this scene will be played out in the next film. Gwen Stacy dies when Green Goblin (Norman Osborn) throws her off a building, and Spiderman, not yet fully adept at using his abilities and tools, catches her with his web, but stops her too fast, and breaks her neck in the process.

---

> So, given that, along with his constant mention throughout the films, odds are the lead villain will be Norman Osborn.

However, the final scene shows the mysterious man disappear from within the cell during a lightning flash. Assuming that the man was literally within the cell, and not just a hallucination of Dr. Connors, that behaviour would indicate either Mysterio (illusionist and escape artist) or Electro (who can merge with and travel via electricity), both of whom have worked under Norman Osborn in the past.

Actual Answer:

> Now that the sequel is out, it turns out the correct answer was Gustav Fiers, aka. The Gentleman.

Comment: Cheers for the spoiler tags in your edit Keen, but 'behaviour' is the correct spelling for basically every country except USA.

Comment: God save the Queen.

Comment: Originally, the man in the ASM1 credits was going to be Electro: http://www.slashfilm.com/sinister-six-mysterio-confirmed/

Answer (score 8):

From [mediastinger](http://www.mediastinger.com/the-amazing-spider-man-2012-extra-scene-during-the-credits/) :

> The extra scene shows an imprisoned Curt Conners who is visited by a mysterious man. A brief exchange of dialogue ensues, and Curt warns him to leave Peter Parker alone. **The man, hidden in the shadows, is believed to be Norman Osborn.**

So :

> Norman Osborn is also known as the [Green Goblin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Goblin).

This is not a proof of the identity of this man since there is no source to the "is believed" section. But this belief seems widespread, since the [cast section of *The Amazing Spider-Man (2012)* on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/fullcredits#cast) got an entry for "Michael Massee" as "Man in the Shadows". The link on "Man in the Shadow" also lead to :

> [Norman Osborn (Character)](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0188711/)

But this proves nothing, as the content of IMDb is suggested to the IMDb database managers by internet users.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the lightning and the fact that the man appears inside the cell and disappears again seemingly with the lightning, im guessing it's probably Max Dillon, AKA Electro.

Comment: I'd say it's Electro. For the lightning and the fact that Electro is more likely of any spider-man villains (besides Kingpin) to manage a group of villains.

Answer (score 4):

It is [**Electro**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro_%28Marvel_Comics%29).

It fits [TheSpacePope's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19970/6365), although the actor who will play Max Dillon in the 2nd movie (Jamie Foxx) is not the same that 'appeared' in the 1st movie (Michael Massee).

Besides having heard Jamie Fox confirming it yesterday (at the Oscars 2013 ceremony), he appears credited both in [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1872181/) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro_%28Marvel_Comics%29#Films).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to say.  It VERY POSSIBLE it could be Norman Osbourn (Green Goblin) since his name has been brought up all through the movie.  But, if you go by the comics, the next movie will reveal Peter's parents as spies against America working for the Red Skull.  However, Peter would learn the truth that they're really CIA agents (see Amazing Spiderman annual 5 for details).  I think Chamelion (brother of Red Skull) will be the next villain.

Comment: Due to license issues, it's doubtful that they will use that storyline. Marvel owns the right to Red Skull, whereas Sony still has Spider Man. It's more likely to be Norman Osborne or another "Spider Man exclusive" villain. It could even be Eddie Brock Sr. If they wanted to sow the seeds for Venom and/or Carnage early to leave their options open for villains and storylines...

Answer (score 0):

The lightning and amazing disappearance and appearance into thin air make me believe its Dr. Strange. He's a master magician and would be able to pull that off.

Comment: Unlikely as Sony doesn't have the rights for Dr. Strange.

Answer (score -1):

Ezekiel, or more likely, the Jackal.

Comment: What makes you think it's one of them?

Comment: I think it likely to be the Jackal also, this fits well with SM history and along with Norman Osbourne would make a great 2nd and 3rd film. If the green goblin is on the cards, I hope they use the version that Raimey originally screen tested - that face was so close to the comics it was unreal.

Comment: @matt please add more detail explaining *why* you think it's the Jakal.  It would also help to add information about who the Jackal is for Spidey non-experts.

Comment: @user7563: "I think it likely to be the Jackal also, this fits well with SM history". Where in Spider-Man history did The Jackal visit Curt Connors in prison, or have anything to do with Peter Parker's parents?